# Synchronize two element values in PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, synchronization, pyqt5

I have a slider and a text box that contains an integer (is there a dedicated integer box?) in PyQt5 shown side by side.

I need these two values to be synchronized, and the way I am doing it right now is with a QtTimer and if statements detecting if one value has changed more recently than the other, and then updating the opposite element. I was told this was "hacky" and was wondering if there was a proper way to do this.

You can see the text box values and sliders that I need to synchronize in the clear areas of the image below.

[image: Interface example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just connect each of the sliders to the other one, straight-forward. I don't know the exact connection you want between the sliders, but it could look something like this.

```
max_player_slider.valueChanged.connect(self.slider1_fu)
npc_stream_slider.valueChanged.conenct(self.slider2_fu)

def slider1_fu(self):
    # do stuff with the npc_stream_slider

def slider2_fu(self):
    # do stuff with the max_player_slider
```

Edit: Here is a [Tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lhCQAngt7ys) that might be helpful.

Comment: I think @spikespaz just wants to synchronise the numeric value with the slider position

Comment: @user3419537 Woops, that is entirely possible. I guess I overshot the problem a bit.. the tutorial I posted still applies, though.

Comment: Yes, the two sets of slider/text boxes are separate, but I will go ahead and watch the tutorial you posted. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I accepted your answer because of the tutorial you posted. I ended up changing the textedit box to a label with a frame around it, and then linking the slider with the label.

Answer (score 4):

The simple solution is to connect the `valueChanged` for each slider/number box to a slot which synchronises the values

```
self.slider1.valueChanged.connect(self.handleSlider1ValueChange)
self.numbox1.valueChanged.connect(self.handleNumbox1ValueChange)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
def handleSlider1ValueChange(self, value):
    self.numbox1.setValue(value)

@QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
def handleNumbox1ValueChange(self.value):
    self.slider1.setValue(value)
```

A better solution is to define a custom slider class that handles everything internally. This way you only have to handle the synchronisation once.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class CustomSlider(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSlider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.handleSliderValueChange)
        self.numbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.numbox.valueChanged.connect(self.handleNumboxValueChange)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.numbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def handleSliderValueChange(self, value):
        self.numbox.setValue(value)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def handleNumboxValueChange(self, value):
        # Prevent values outside slider range
        if value < self.slider.minimum():
            self.numbox.setValue(self.slider.minimum())
        elif value > self.slider.maximum():
            self.numbox.setValue(self.slider.maximum())

        self.slider.setValue(self.numbox.value())

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
slider1 = CustomSlider()
slider2 = CustomSlider()
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()
layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(window)
layout.addWidget(slider1)
layout.addWidget(slider2)
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

---

**Edit**: With regard to comments from ekhumoro, the above class can be simplified to

```
class CustomSlider(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSlider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.numbox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        self.numbox.setRange(self.slider.minimum(), self.slider.maximum())
        self.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.numbox.setValue)
        self.slider.rangeChanged.connect(self.numbox.setRange)
        self.numbox.valueChanged.connect(self.slider.setValue)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.numbox)
        layout.addWidget(self.slider)
```

You'll probably also want to mimic some of the `QSlider` methods to change the range and value. Note we don't need to explicitly set anything on `self.numbox` as the signal/slot connections made above take care of it.

```
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setMinimum(self, minval):
        self.slider.setMinimum(minval)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setMaximum(self, maxval):
        self.slider.setMaximum(maxval)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def setRange(self, minval, maxval):
        self.slider.setRange(minval, maxval)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def setValue(self, value):
        self.slider.setValue(value)
```

Comment: The slider and spinbox already have the required slots, so you can just do: `slider.valueChanged.connect(spinbox.setValue)`. There's also no need to do any bounds-checking - the user *cannot* enter values outside the min/max range set on the slider/spinbox (which obviously needs to be the same for each).

Comment: I intended it to be a more generic example of user defined slots, but you're right, it's overkill for this question. Good point on the bounds checking though. I didn't consider you could set limits on the spinbox. I'll update with your suggestions

Comment: Your solution is better than the one that was accepted, because it uses spinboxes. This really simplifies things, because the APIs of sliders and spinboxes are so similar. Your example code doesn't really emphasize that simplicty, though.